# assembly, segmentation fault

Tags: assembly, x86

This code results in a segmentation fault, I have no idea why it does it,
The code just supposed to pass the current location of esp at the stack to ebp
and just use indirect addressing mode on ebp to get the value of the address, 
I don't know why the OS is terminating which results in segmentation fault

```
.section .data
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
movl $50,%edx
pushl, %edx
movl %esp,%ebp
movl (%ebp),%ebx  ## this causes the problem for some reason, 
movl $1,%eax     
int $0x80         ## Program should return an exit status of %ebx value
```

Comment: If you have the C code, please post it.

Comment: R sahu , Hey , the stackoverflow, suggest i should post my post at the c section also, I have no C code for this, example.

Comment: Works for me. The only issue that could occur is that you're not properly cleaning up the stack (there is a `push` without a matching `pop`), but since all you're doing in the process is issuing a system call, this shouldn't matter.

Comment: Also you have an extra comma in `pushl,%edx` but I hope that's just copy-paste error. Furthermore we hope you are running this on linux in 32 bit mode. You forgot to give these important details, along with the command lines you used to build it.

Comment: Jester, Oh yeah, that just a copy-paste problem, also guys, when i used .code32 at the top of my program it still results in segmentation fault

Comment: @abba: If you tell it to generate 32-bit code, but the process is 64-bit, then it's going to crash. You'd need to tell it to generate 32-bit code and make sure it's actually executed as 32-bit code (and not just 32-bit code within a 64-bit ELF executable).

Comment: Brendan, i am just using as test.s -o test.o;ld test.o -o test; there are any parameters i should add to the linker or the assembler?

Comment: What does `file test` say?

Comment: i echo $?, which should echo the result of the return , but instead it just segmentation fault

Comment: Please run the command `file test` and tell us the output.

Comment: ELF 64-bit LSB executeable ,x86-64, Version 1 (SYSV),staticlly linked,not stripped

Comment: See, that's the problem. You managed to compile it as 64 bit code. Not sure how, since `pushl %edx` does not even assemble. Anyway, use `as --32 test.s -o test.o; ld -melf_i386 test.o -o test` to create a 32 bit version properly.

Comment: Jester, I added, I added .code32 at the top of my file

Comment: Ah yeah, that does force the poor assembler to accept it, thinking you know what you are doing :)  Use the commands I showed to create 32 bit code.

Comment: code seems to work , lol this is weird, i didn't even expected the ELF header will be 64 bit :P, thanks Jester . appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

As Jester says, the problem is that 64bit Linux tools default to making 64bit programs.  He has a bad habit of writing his answers in comments, so I'll just duplicate it here:

```
as --32 test.s -o test.o; ld -melf_i386 test.o -o test
```

or

```
gcc -m32 foo.s -ffreestanding -nostdlib -o foo
```

You segfault at

```
movl (%ebp),%ebx
```

because `%rsp` isn't all-zero in the upper 32 bits, so `%esp` is a different address from `%rsp`.  You could find this problem with gdb.  You'd have noticed that you had 64bit registers.  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for info on using gdb for asm.

I'm going to pick on this line some more:

```
pushl, %edx
```

Besides being a syntax error (extra comma), `_start` doesn't need to save any registers.  The [x86-64 ABI says](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) you should assume they're all full of random garbage, except the stack pointer.  It also says `%rdx` has the address of a function you should register with `atexit()`, but on current Linux, `%rdx` is zeroed on process entry.  (Command line args are on the stack.)

I presume things are pretty much the same for x86 32bit process startup.

Comment: (Update: RDX is non-zero when your `_start` is invoked by ld.so in a dynamically-linked executable.  It's a callback function pointer for destructors for shared libraries.  RDX and other regs except RSP are 0 in `_start` in a *statically* linked executable in Linux, to avoid information leaks, but in a dynamic executable other regs can hold garbage.)