# Linux assembly x86 | trying to get stack value, syntax error

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I have been messing around with linux assembly on an x86 machine,
Basically my question is: I have pushed couple values into the stack moved the stack pointer into the base pointer and moved a value of 8 into a register to get a pushed value and in the end i wanted to get the value and put it into %ebx for the system call so i would get the value, but it seems to get an error. no clue why.
Error is: junk `(%ebp)` after register
Example:

```
.section .data
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
pushl $50
pushl $20
movl %esp,%ebp
movl $8,%edx
movl %edx(%ebp),%ebx ## Supposed to be return value at system termination // PROBLEM HERE
movl $1,%eax ## System call
int $0x80 # Terminate program
```

Comment: Looks like the same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31887645/assembly-segmentation-fault.  32bit asm built into a 64bit binary, truncating pointers.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I think part of the problem might be that in `x86` the stack actually grows downwards, not up. You're adding to the base pointer, which is giving junk, where you have to subtract from it. I don't have an `x86` machine so I can't test this, but have you tried something like `movl -%edx(%ebp),%ebx`?</strike>

Oops, I reversed the direction of the operands in my head. In this case, your stack looks like this:

```
1952 - ???
1948 - 20
1944 - 50                  <- ebp  <- esp
```

So when you take `ebp+8`, you aren't getting 20, you're getting address 1952, and you don't know what that contains.

Comment: Its always going to be a plus since the stack pointer is passed to the base pointer after the value already has been pushed into the stack.

Comment: you're right. For some reason I thought you moved ebp into esp, not the other way around

Comment: Hey, I have actually dereffrenced the ebp with the () with indirect mode, seems really weird to me,

Answer (score 0):

Check out the links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info.  I updated them recently, and added the info about using `gdb` to single-step asm.

What do you mean "get an error"?    Segmentation fault?  Syntax error?  (The normal syntax is `(%ebp, %edx)`.  Only numeric-constant displacements go outside the parens, e.g. `-4(%ebp, %edx)`)

Also, if you're going to use stack frame pointers at all, do the  `mov %esp, %ebp` after `push`ing any registers you want to preserve, but before pushing args to any functions you're going to call.  However, there's no need to use `%ebp` that way at all, though.  gcc defaults to `-fomit-frame-pointer` since 4.4 I think.  It can make it easier to keep track of where your local variables are, if you're pushing/popping stuff.

You might want to just start with 64bit asm, instead of messing around with the obsolete x86 args-on-the-stack ABI.

This just made me think of what's probably wrong with your code.  You're probably getting a segfault.  (But you didn't say if it was that, syntax error, or something else.)  Because you probably built your code in 64bit mode.  [Build a 32bit binary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31889258/224132), or change your code to use `%rsp`.

You might want to just start with 64bit asm, instead of messing around with the obsolete x86 args-on-the-stack ABI.

This just made me think of what's probably wrong with your code.  You're probably getting a segfault.  (But you didn't say if it was that, syntax error, or something else.)  Because you probably built your code in 64bit mode.  [Build a 32bit binary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31889258/224132), or change your code to use `%rsp`.

Comment: Hey Peter, it doesn't even assemble cause of syntax error, but what extacly is the syntax error anyway?, I am not an idiot that runs the program on 64 bit ELF.. , i'm using as --32 ; and linking it with melf_i386, but it doesn't matter cause its not compiling

Comment: @Mike: you did a terrible job of making it clear what the problem was in your question.  I even had a paragraph about how that was weird-looking syntax, but I took it out because I assumed it must work, or you would have posted the error message.

Comment: What's the alleged error? Returns `argc`, no problem!

Comment: @Mike: I luckily still had the paragraph in my clipboard history, so I put it back in.

Comment: Error is: junk `(%ebp)` after register

Comment: @Mike: See my 2nd paragraph.  It has an example of the correct syntax.  Alternatively, just `objdump -d /bin/ls | less` or something.  Actually nvm, I just did that and 2-register addressing modes appear quite rare.  Compiler output from a C function that does what you want can be a good place to start writing an optimized asm version, though.

Comment: Peter, i don't want it to be a CONSTANT, i want it to be a value in %edx, that will be used in a loop and each time i wiill add 4 into %edx, to get all pushed parameters

Comment: @Mike: holy crap dude, go read some docs and manuals.  `(%ebp, %ebx)` is the AT&T version of `[ebp + ebx]`.  It's the correct syntax for what you're trying to do.

Comment: This is not FASM,nor NASM. its GNU assembly

Comment: @Mike: Yes, GNU asm is AT&T syntax, where `(%ebp, %ebx, 1)` is what you want.  You can disassemble in either syntax, to make sure that the machine code that got generated is what you wanted.